# Generate POCO objects from xml file

Tags: c#, xml, linq, poco

I have an XML file which roughly describes a database schema I am inheriting

I want to generate POCO objects for this file to give me a head start with the business objects in my C# application.

Is this possible and how?

Comment: If you give us an example of what your XML file looks like, we might give you a head start.

Answer (score 8):

You could (and should) define a [xsd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_schema) which describes your XML file. From this XSD you can generate classes using [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

If you need more control over your code generation (e.g. you aren't happy with the output of xsd.exe, want to add attributes, make changes, ...) you can use [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaImporter, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlCodeExporter and CodeDom](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2007/01/writing-your-own-xsdexe.html) to adjust the generated code.

Answer (score 4):

Yes,it can be done. Take a look at T4 text templetes
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx

Comment: You can use T4 templates in some awesome ways. I have used them in ASP.NET MVC and generated entire CRUD pages from my data model classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SimpleXmlToCode](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplexmltocode/) .It does not require an XSD or anything. It generates good serializable code instantly.

Best of all, it's opensource.